# NHibernate Parent and Child Tables have different number of keys in their composite

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I'm struggling a bit with an NHibernate mapping within a console app.

Here is the summary:

- It's a one to many relationship. PARENT_TABLE (one) to CHILD_TABLE (many)
- PARENT_TABLE has a composite key consisting of two keys: Vendor and
  Invoice

```
Id(x => x.Invoice).Column("INVOICE");

References(x => x.Distribution).Column("INVOICE");
```

- CHILD_TABLE has a composite key consisting of three: Vendor,
  Invoice, and Num

```
Id(x => x.Invoice).Column("INVOICE");

HasOne(x => x.Invoice).ForeignKey("INVOICE").Cascade.Refresh();
```

---

When I run through some data that has the following example:

Vendor Invoice Num

10  |   44   |   1

11  |   44   |   1

11  |   44   |   2

I end up getting an error because of the duplicate ID in Invoice (Makes total sense)

Then, I tried using a composite ID using 3 keys for Distribution and 2 keys for Invoice. This, as I'm sure many of you already know, also ended up with an error since there are two records that use 11 and 44 for Vendor and Invoice, respectively.

My question: Is there a way to declare the relationship using a composite ID (INVOICE and VENDOR) and still have the child collection respect/enforce the uniqueness of the 3 key composite (INVOICE, VENDOR, and NUM)?

I've tried several permutations of composite keys and haven't been able to figure it out. Maybe it's just not designed for this. Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Given you have a composite id definition on your entities, you have to map it using the `CompositeId` method. In your child entity, you also have to define the references for key columns of your parent entity, because it is a composite id (and that's the reason where I personally do not enjoy working with composite IDs).

Considering your model:

```
public class ParentEntity 
{
    public virtual int Vendor { get; set; }
    public virtual int Invoice { get; set; }

    // other properties
}

public class ChildEntity
{
    public virtual int Vendor { get; set; }
    public virtual int Invoice { get; set; }
    public virtual int Num { get; set; }

    public virtual ParentEntity ParentEntity { get; set; }
}
```

Your mappings could be like this:

```
public class ParentEntityMap : ClassMap<ParentEntity>
{
    public ParentEntityMap()
    {
        CompositeId()
            .KeyProperty(x => x.Vendor, "VENDOR")
            .KeyProperty(x => x.Invoice, "INVOICE");

        // other mappings ...
    }
}

public class ChildEntityMap : ClassMap<ChildEntity>
{
    public ChildEntity()
    {
        CompositeId()
            .KeyProperty(x => x.Vendor, "VENDOR")
            .KeyProperty(x => x.Invoice, "INVOICE")
            .KeyProperty(x => x.Num, "NUM");

        References(x => x.ParentEntity)
            .Columns("VENDOR", "INVOICE")
            .ReadOnly(); // if you are mapping the same columns of compositeId here, define it as readOnly to avoid inserting data two times on the same columns.
    }
}
```

I did not try this code, it is just a suggestion to check what could work for you.